# Why does React need to connect to a server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I just started working with React and I came to 2 big questions that I never realized before:

1. Why does React need to connect to a server (localhost, deployment, etc)? Isn't it usually the backend that needs the server url, not the frontend? From my frontend experience, I would just have a .js file with jQuery doing the DOM scripting for the associated html file and that was it.
2. If I am making a React full stack application with let's say a .NET backend, then React will have its localhost:3000 server url and the .NET backend (ASP.NET Core) would have something like a localhost:54204. Does that mean I need 2 deployments to run that application? Is that normal, or is there some process to mesh the two?

Thank you so much for answering this, hopefully these 2 questions answered will make me fully grasp the concept of React

Comment: I think your first question is not something you have in production. The network activity you see is to reload when you make changes. It's called hot module reloading. When you make a production build you get static js files but during development you can make xhr request to the "same server" by setting up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Answer (score 1):

For the first question  does react have server and why? Yes it has and its in the bundler which is called webpack. In fact it runs server script under hood and it is for development. What about the deployment when you  use create-react-app and finish your app  you can run npm run buld it creates a folder for bundled files. So you can use it in your backend a static files or can create different server script and deploy as an independent application.